# Why am I getting an error that says there's no view data for my dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

My model links 2 tables in the database so I need to allow my users to select an item in the secondary table when creating a new record in the primary table.

The tables I'm linking are `Roles` and `Users`

In the case of user roles, when you create a new user record you would select a role from a dropdownlist. The user model would look summing like this:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int RoleId { get; set; }
public Role Role { get; set; }
public string Username { get; set; }
...
```

On the form you'll select a Role from the dropdownlist which will give you the value for RoleId which can then be used to select the Role from the database:

```
@Html.DropDownList("RoleId", "Please select a user role.")
```

The problem I'm having with this (although I've got this working in another project from which I've copied the code) is that there's apparently no view data for the `<select>` element.

Actual error text below:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'RoleId'.

Any idea what I've done wrong here?

Comment: Ise Role another table in DB?

Comment: can you show how <select> is populated on view?

Comment: You need to provide us with your *actual* code for the view model. Create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your example is not Complete, because we can't see how you're creating the view model and getting it to the HTML helper. Seems likely the arguments you're passing are incorrect.

Comment: Sadly I can't, because the page never actually renders

Answer (score 1):

You're using an invalid overload for `.DropDownList`. There is no signature that just takes in two strings. You have to specify the values it's going to use when generating the select list.

Use the overload that takes in an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. For example:

```
@Html.DropDownList("RoleId", Model.ListOfRoles, "Please select a user role.")
```

If you're creating a new list, you can use the ViewBag:

```
// SelectList(List<Role>, "Data Value Field", "Data Text Field");
ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleId", "RoleName");

@Html.DropDownList("RoleId", "Please select a role for this user")
```

Comment: I'm working on a 1-1 relationship here. 1 role per user. No use should ever have more than 1 role.

Comment: @Ortund, You still need to pass in a list of selectable roles. How else is the view going to render a drop down list unless you tell it what the options are? When the user selects a value from the drop down list, then that option's value will be bound to `RoleId`.

Comment: How could it be bound to RoleId when RoleId is only taking a single value? 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc...

Comment: @Ortund, there are two relevant properties when using Html.DropDownList. The property that is going to hold the selected value, and the collection of selectable options. When I choose the "Administrator" role from the drop down list which has a value of `1`, then when I post the model to the controller, `RoleId` will have the value of 1. (And Model.ListOfRoles will be null, you'll have to re-bind every time you redisplay the view)

Comment: Right... I forgot about this from the older project `ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleId", "RoleName", user.RoleId);`